# Best software to Stream data from online to a game engine

Tags: game-development

I'd like to stream data from an online source into a game engine. I've been looking at Unity, Unreal Engine 4 and CryEngine but have not found out if anyone has streamed data from a webserver to any of these engines.

Can anyone here who has experience in a game engine comment on whether what I want to do is possible and which engine they recommend?

Thanks